# OracleDataReader Exception when Select a Blob type Column

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, oracle10g, odp.net

I'm attempting to retrieve an EmptyBLOB from an Oracle database to next write a byte array on that column but I keep getting an Exception Message   "ORA-03135: Connection lost contact" in the oracle Data Reader when ExecuteReader. If I select any other column of the table in the statement it works fine. The oracle database is 10g 10.2.0.4.0 - 64bit and I'm using the Oracle.ManagedDataAccess as ODP for .NET

```
oracleConnection.Open();
OracleCommand nameFile = oracleConnection.CreateCommand();
nameFile.Connection = oracleConnection;
nameFile.Transaction = nameFile.Connection.BeginTransaction();
nameFile.CommandText = "Delete from CF2 WHERE COMPANY_EMPID_FOLIO = :pCOMPANY_EMPID_FOLIO";
nameFile.Parameters.Add("pCOMPANY_EMPID_FOLIO", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 15).Value = sFolio;
nameFile.ExecuteNonQuery();
nameFile.CommandText = "insert into CF2 (COMPANY_EMPID_FOLIO, XML_AND_PDF_ZIP, CREATED_DATE, CREATED_BY, LAST_UPDATE_DATE, LAST_UPDATE_BY) values(:pCOMPANY_EMPID_FOLIO,EMPTY_BLOB(), sysdate, :pUser, sysdate, :pUser)";
nameFile.Parameters.Add("pUser", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 10).Value = sUser;
nameFile.ExecuteNonQuery();
nameFile.Parameters.Clear();

nameFile.CommandText = "SELECT COMPANY_EMPID_FOLIO, XML_AND_PDF_ZIP FROM CF2 WHERE COMPANY_EMPID_FOLIO = :pCOMPANY_EMPID_FOLIO FOR UPDATE"; // XML_AND_PDF_ZIP is BLOP Type Column
nameFile.Parameters.Add("pCOMPANY_EMPID_FOLIO", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 15).Value = sFolio;
OracleDataReader oracleDataReader = nameFile.ExecuteReader(); //DB Lost Contact in this point if a include the blop column in the Select
OracleDataReader oracleDataReader1 = oracleDataReader;

try
{
    oracleDataReader.Read();
    OracleLob oracleLob = oracleDataReader.GetOracleLob(1);
    oracleLob.Write(bytes, 0, (int)bytes.Length);
}
finally
{
    if (oracleDataReader1 != null)
    {
        ((IDisposable)oracleDataReader1).Dispose();
    }
}
```

Is there something else I'm missing before the .read method ?

Comment: Did you miss to add the parameter _:pCOMPANY_EMPID_FOLIO_ in the Insert query?

Comment: Before insert query I got a delete query where I add that parameter, I'll update the post to add that query

Comment: What if you just do `if (!DbNull.Value.Equals(reader["blob_col"])) byte[] bytes = (byte[])reader["blob_col"];` ??

Comment: Most likely theres an error in the alert log on the database server corresponding to the lost connection. Searching on that error number will shed more light.

Comment: A timeout perhaps? Does the query hang for a while then issue this error?

Comment: Why do you select FOR UPDATE when you never update the selected records?