# Reading a BLOB from Oracle Database with C# using ODP .NET

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, blob

I'm having problems getting a Blob from Oracle DB, I'm doing a simple C# console Project trying sample exercises from google trying to figure out whats the problem. 
I'm making a Select Statement to getting the data. This program works but if I include the blob type column("XML_AND_PDF_ZIP") which is the column I want from the table I get the error ORA-03135: Connection Lost Contact Tips when the Read() method of the OracleDataReader Object executes.

I'm using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess as my ODP .NET provider. The Oracle Database version is 10g 10.2 64bit.
Am I missing something before the ExecuteReader() method hits ??

```
private static string GetConnectionString(string _connectionID)
        {
            return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[_connectionID].ConnectionString;
        }

    public static List<CF2> GetOraBlob(string sFolio)
    {
        try
        {
            List<CF2> result = new List<CF2>();
            using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(GetConnectionString(connectionID)))
            {
                using (OracleCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
                {

                    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT COMPANY_EMPID_FOLIO, XML_AND_PDF_ZIP  FROM CF2 WHERE COMPANY_EMPID_FOLIO = :pCOMPANY_EMPID_FOLIO FOR UPDATE"; //XML_AND_PDF_ZIP is the Blob Column
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("pCOMPANY_EMPID_FOLIO", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 15).Value = sFolio;
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.BindByName = true;
                    conn.Open();
                    using (OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                            while (reader.Read()) //Get ORA-03135 Error If the Blob Column is in the Select Statement
                            {

                                CF2 data = new CF2();
                                data.Folio = reader["COMPANY_EMPID_FOLIO"].ToString();
                                data.OraBlob = Convert.ToByte(reader["XML_AND_PDF_ZIP"]);
                                result.Add(data);

                            }

                    }
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: A duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60104421/oracledatareader-exception-when-select-a-blob-type-column) ?

Comment: You cannot connect to an Oracle 10g database with the ODP.NET Managed Driver version 12. I wonder that you don't get an error already when you open the connection.

Comment: I don't get an error when I open connection, in fact, I can select any other column of the table CF2 which are varchar columns and read the values and display them on the console.
Something odd is that I use NuGet package to install Oracle ManagedDataAccess, version 19.6 and that's the version I saw installed when I check the NuGet Package manager but when I check the version from solution explorer in the references > properties it says the version is 4.122.19.1

Answer (score 1):

Some time ago a had similar problem and I use this solution:

Create a PL/SQL Function:

```
FUNCTION GetBlob(pCOMPANY_EMPID_FOLIO IN NUMBER) RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR IS
    res SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
    OPEN res FOR 
    SELECT XML_AND_PDF_ZIP  
    FROM CF2 
    WHERE COMPANY_EMPID_FOLIO = pCOMPANY_EMPID_FOLIO;
    RETURN res; 
END GetBlob;
```

And call it like this:

```
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("BEGIN res := GetBlob(:primaryKey); END;"), ora.Connection);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("res", OracleDbType.RefCursor, ParameterDirection.ReturnValue);
cmd.Parameters.Add("primaryKey", OracleDbType.Int32, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = sFolio;
cmd.InitialLOBFetchSize = 16384;
using (OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader() ) {
   dr.Read();
   OracleBlob blob = dr.GetOracleBlob(0);
   MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(blob.Value);
   dr.Close();
}
```

Note, my application uses the ODP.NET Unmanaged Driver. Perhaps your issue is due to a bug in the Managed Driver.